# Database design - if column value repeats itself mutiple times should I put it in another table and reference it in main table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am making a computer hardware database, that will list hardware specifications.

My question is if a column value repeats itself mutiple times in the database, should I put it in another table and then reference it, with foreign key?

ER Diagram example
[image]

For example CPU series.
Mutiple cpus can have 1 series of cpu - Core i7, core i5, core I3. Should I keep Series in `Cpu` table, or should I make series table and then reference it to `cpus` table as in ER?
Same thing is for `cpu_grahpics`, and `cpu_core` table, that values repeats mutiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't solve repeating values by hiding them behind a surrogate key, since you're simply representing one value by another.  The surrogate key will repeat in the place of the original value, and now you have to deal with a level of indirection to get meaningful values.

There are other reasons for introducing surrogate keys.  Names are often verbose, can have multiple representations, not stable and need to be localized.

More important than watching for repeating values is to watch for repeating dependencies.  For example, if I'm reading your diagram correctly, the functional dependency `cpu_core_id -> cpu_core_name` is recorded in both `Cpu` and `cpu_cores`.  This could allow different `cpu_core_name` values to be associated with the same `cpu_core_id`, resulting in your data being inconsistent.

This can happen in a single table, not just among multiple tables.  Since multiple CPUs could be built on the same core, having `cpu_core_id -> cpu_core_name` in the `Cpu` table would have to record the same id-to-name mapping multiple times (this is called a transitive functional dependency).  If any of the multiple instances of a specific core had a different name associated with it, your data would be inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This type of table is called a junction table.  It allows you to define foreign key relationships and to make use of indexes.  I would imagine a table called something like `CPUSeries` with one row per CPU and each series.

EDIT:

From your description, you would want:

```
create table CPUs (
    CPUId int auto_increment primary key,
    . . .
);

create table Series (
    SeriesId int auto_increment primary key,
    CPUId int not null,
    . . .
    constraint fk_series_cpuid foreign key (CPUId) references CPUs(CPUId)
);
```

This is just a nested relationship.  You would put the columns in the appropriate tables for normalization purposes.

Comment: @hulapouanusaka . . . I think it is the same idea.  You would conceptually have a `CPUSeries` table with a foreign key relationship to the `CPUs` table.  There would be no need for a `Series` table, if those are uniquely identified by the `CPUSeries` table.  (And you might call the two tables `Series` and `CPUs`.

Comment: Thank you both of you, now i got it :)